# Считывание одного символа с консоли

Tags: c, char

Как можно считать один символ с консоли?

Например: "Вы уверены? (Д)а, (Н)ет."

Comment: Что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: Ничего..... : )

Comment: Как, даже main () нет?  Попробуйте, у вас есть ещё время.

Comment: scanf()  - считывание символа) P.s а так поправьте вопрос , что именно не получилось ?

Comment: Спасибо, но scanf() просто пропускает ввод :(

Comment: @ВладиславАнатольевич Приведите весь код. Может, вы перед этим scanf'ом какой int читали, да и забыли буфер сбросить?

Answer (score 2):

Нострадамлю :), что перед этим где-то было считывание в духе `scanf("%d"` без сброса после этого буфера ввода, так что в нем остался `\n`, который и считывается следующим `scanf`.

Проверьте, сбросили ли вы буфер (`fflush` тут ни при чем, если что), и если нет - попробуйте сбросить...

Ну, и второй вариант - неверная кодировка, если вы именно русские символы читаете...

По совету @AndrejLevkovitch: сброс буфера - это считать остаток строки в никуда :) - например,

```
for(int c = getchar (); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar ());
```

Comment: Добавлю, что после какого-либо ввода, после которого нужно считать символы, лучше добовлять код: while (getchar () != '\n') continue;

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Так это и есть сброс буфера ввода...

Comment: Я так думаю, что лучше привести код - если он не знает, что в буфере остаются непрочтенные символы, то межет и не знает как их пропустить.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно ввод с клавиатуры приходит в программу построчно. В Си нет стандартного переносимого способа прочитать один символ с консоли, не дожидаясь <kbd>Enter</kbd> клавиши. [comp.lang.c FAQ: How can I read a single character from the keyboard without waiting for the RETURN key?](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html)

Другими словами: `getchar()` не вернётся пока `'\n'` не встретится (что может произойти после ввода многих многих символов). Чтобы не дожидаясь новой строки прочитать один символ из Windows консоли, [можно `_getche()`/`_getwche()` из `conio.h` использовать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getche-getwche).

На Unix, необходимо изменить режим терминала, чтобы посимвольный ввод получать и самостоятельно восстановить предыдущие настройки при выходе из программы. К примеру, используя `curses` библиотеку, [можно `cbreak` режим использовать](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/intov.html#tag_001_005_002):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();
  cbreak(); // change terminal mode to accept a char at a time

  // get answer
  int c;
  do {
    mvaddstr(0, 0, "Are you sure? (Y)es/(N)o: ");
    c = getch();
    c = toupper((unsigned char)c);
  } while (c != 'Y' && c != 'N');

  endwin(); // restore terminal settings

  return c == 'N';
}
```

Пример:

```
$ cc *.c -lcurses && ./a.out && echo yes || echo no
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим нужно узнать подтверждение от юзера и записать в переменную для этого подходит функция `scanf();` и научитесь работать с УПРАВЛЯЮЩИМИ ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНАСТЯМИ  `scanf ("%c",&i);` записывает в переменную i один символ а вот %s уже несколько символов. Что бы быть точно уверенным можете заключить это в цикл с проверкой введённых данных

```
do {scanf ("%c",&i);}while (!(i == 'Y')||(i == 'N'));
```

Comment: Спасибо, но scanf() почему-то пропускает ввод :(

Comment: Код неверный...